# using html input with jsf form

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, jsf, jsf-2

I work on a jsf 2.2 application and I want to use Bootstrap. 
So I downloaded Bootstrap template and tried to adapt it.
But when I use h:inputText it doesn't look good like when I use Html input 
That's why I ve used Html input but in the managed bean I had to use this code in order to get input's value.

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    nom=req.getParameter("name");
```

I'am not sure if it's an optimal choice or not, because I don't really use the benefits of jsf.

Comment: *"But when I use h:inputText it doesn't look good like when I use Html input"* then you was using it in a wrong way. You'd better take a step back, edit and reframe your question to ask how to use it correctly while showing your attempt and telling the expected HTML output. One of the benefits of JSF is that you don't need to manually fiddle with request parameters anymore (and conversion/validation on those).

Answer (score -1):

You can also use javascript. Add a listener for your form submit or button click to update a hidden field (`<h:input type="hidden"/>`) value with your HTML field new value before form is submitted. and bind the value of that hidden field to back bean property.

But i don't suggest using this approach because your code base will be a mess after some time, if you are writing JSF, you must fully use JSF features.

The harder but more standard way of doing this is to  create a **custom JSF Component** .

To do this, you must extend  `UIComponentBase` class in JSF and then register your renderer as a new component like this:

```
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/JSF/Configuration">
   <component>
   <component-type>tss.hello.JsfHello</component-type>
   <component-class>tss.hello.HelloUIComp</component-class>
</component>
 ...
</faces-config>
```

Then you need to add this component as a taglib like this (TLD file in WebINF folder):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE taglib
  PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JSP Tag Library 1.2//EN" 
  "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-jsptaglibrary_1_2.dtd">
<taglib>
<tlib-version>0.01</tlib-version>
<jsp-version>1.2</jsp-version>
<short-name>simple</short-name>
<uri>http://theserverside.com/simplefacescomponents</uri>
<description>This tag library contains simple JSF Component examples.</description>


<tag>
<name>jsfhello</name>
<tag-class>tss.hello.FacesHelloTag</tag-class>

<attribute> 
<name>binding</name> 
<description>A value binding that points to a bean property</description>
</attribute> 

<attribute> 
<name>id</name> 
<description>The client id of this component</description>
</attribute> 

<attribute> 
<name>rendered</name>
<description>Is this component rendered?</description>
</attribute>

<attribute> 
<name>hellomsg</name>
<description>a custom message for the Component</description>
</attribute>

</tag>

</taglib>
```

You can then use your tag like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=windows-1252"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://theserverside.com/customfacescomponents" prefix="cf"%>
<f:view>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"></meta>
    </head>
    <body>
     <h:form>

     <p>A simple HelloWorld Custom Component:</p>

     <p>The HelloWorld UI Component:</p>
     <cf:jsfhello hellomsg="Hello world! This is output from a custom JSF Component!"   />


     </h:form>
    </body>
  </html>
</f:view>
```

See [this link](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364786/Building-Custom-JSF-UI-Components) for complete Custom component tutorial

Comment: OP is using JSF 2.x not JSF 1.x. This answer assumes JSF 1.x. Moreover, a custom component is absolutely overkill if setting proper Bootstrap styles is matter of setting only one attribute right, which is nowhere covered in this answer.

Comment: Yes that's correct, i assumed he want to use his custom tag anyway. thank you.